# Why should there be spaces around '[' and ']' in Bash?

Tags: bash, if-statement, syntax

I was trying to write a Bash script that uses an `if` statement.

```
if[$CHOICE -eq 1];
```

The script was giving me errors until I gave a space before and after `[` and before `]` as shown below:

```
if [ $CHOICE -eq 1 ];
```

My question here is, why is the space around the square brackets so important in Bash?

Comment: The general syntax is `if command; then commands_if_exit_code_is_0; else commands_if_exit_code_is_nonzero; fi;`. *`command`* can be any command, and `[` is just one of them.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4977367/why-equal-to-operator-does-not-work-if-its-not-surrounded-by-space (you need spaces around the operator, too).

Comment: See this related post: [Is double square brackets preferable over single square brackets in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/669452/6862601).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268104/command-not-found-error-in-bash-variable-assignment/2268117#2268117

Comment: If `$CHOICE` is `"foo"`, you are attempting to run the command `["foo"`.

Comment: In Bash, `[[` obeys the same requirements; you need spaces on both sides, and the command needs to end with `]]`. The doubled version is somewhat more versatile and robust; see the link by @codeforester above for a more nuanced discussion.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Once you grasp that **`[`** is a ***command***, a whole lot becomes clearer!

**`[`** is another way to spell "`test`".

```
help [
```

However while they do *exactly* the same, `test` turns out to have a more detailed help page. Check

```
help test
```

...for more information.

---

Furthermore note that I'm using, by intention, `help test` and not `man test`. That's because `test` and `[` are shell builtin commands nowadays. Their feature set might differ from `/bin/test` and `/bin/[` from coreutils which are the commands described in the `man` pages.

Comment: and originally, it was at `/usr/bin/[` and was a hardlink to `/usr/bin/test`, when invoked as `[` you should include a closing brace as last argument. Now it's a shell builtin.

Comment: Note that they are not quite "exactly" the same.  `[` requires that its last argument be `]`.

Answer (score 19):

From [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035396/bash-shell-script-syntax-error):

> A bit of history: this is because '[' was historically not a shell-built-in but a separate executable that received the expresson as arguments and returned a result. If you didn't surround the '[' with space, the shell would be searching $PATH for a different filename (and not find it) . – [Andrew Medico](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19405/andrew-medico) Jun 24 '09 at 1:13

Answer (score 9):

`[` is a command and `$CHOICE` should be an argument, but by doing `[$CHOICE` (without any space between `[` and `$CHOICE`) you are trying to run a command named `[$CHOICE`. The syntax for command is:

```
command arguments separated with space
```

Answer (score 3):

`[` is a `test` command. So it requires space.

Answer (score 3):

It's worth noting that [ is also used in glob matching, which can get you into trouble.

```
$ echo [12345]
[12345]
$ echo oops >3
$ echo [12345]
3
```

Comment: In case it's not obvious what's going on here, in the first case you don't happen to have any file which matches the wildcard expression `[12345]` so the shell leaves it unexpanded. But when there is a file named `3`, that's what the wildcard expands to.