# Conditional in shell

Tags: shell

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c '  if [cat ${1} == "abc" ]   then  echo ${1} fi' _ {} \;
```

I got this error:

```
_: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

What I what to do here is :

find all files in this directory, print file name if file content is abc.

Thank you !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why should there be a space after '\[' and before '\]' in a Bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581064/why-should-there-be-a-space-after-and-before-in-a-bash-script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the `[` (aka 'test') needs to be separated from `cat` by a space, like so:

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'if [ cat ${1} = "abc" ]; then  echo ${1}; fi' _ {} \;
```

You're also missing semicolons after the `if` statement and before the `fi` statement (it looks like you had these on separate lines originally, based on the spacing that was there, probably due to the way that you had it indented)

As pointed out in the comment below, running this will give the error message `too many arguments in if []`. Using double quotes around `"cat ${1}"` will avoid the error message, but this simply compares the expansion of `"cat ${1}"` with `"abc"`. What you're probably looking for is `[ "$(cat ${1})" == "abc" ]`. Unfortunately, this is likely to cause problems when you compare a very long file with `"abc"`.

You could use `grep` to do the test, or take a checksum (e.g. `shasum`) of the file, and test that against the checksum of `"abc"`, depending on what why you're doing the test.

Comment: `[ foo == bar ]` isn't valid POSIX, but a bash extension. Use `[ foo = bar ]` if you want to be compatible with baseline POSIX shells.

Comment: Just changed that in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Put spaces after '[' and before ']' and a ';' after the ']'

another way is to use

```
[ `cat ${1}` == "abc" ] && echo ${1}
```

Comment: Actually if you want to compare the result of the cat you need to use backquotes (I edit the answer to reflect that)

Comment: thanks @Teudinundo. I figured out another way is  "$()" , haha not so elegent as yours.

Comment: @AndersLind -- actually `$()` is better, because it's easier to nest.