# How to write shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I want to write a shell that runs until something is written to a file (by another process). I have written this:

```
PID_FILE=log.txt
DONE=0
while [$DONE -eq 0]
do 
    cat $PID_FILE | while read LINE 
    do
    if [$LINE -neq ""]; then    
        echo "Do stuff here"
        $DONE=1
    fi  
    done
done    
echo "DONE"
echo "">$PID_FILE
```

but I get

```
test.sh: 3: test.sh: [0: not found
DONE
```

Comment: [$DONE -eq 0] =>  [ $DONE -eq 0 ], btw you can use the test program in place of the [ command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This line:

```
while [$DONE -eq 0]
```

Needs spaces around the square brackets:

```
while [ $DONE -eq 0 ]
```

As does this one:

```
if [$LINE -neq ""]; then
```

Like this:

```
if [ $LINE -neq "" ]; then
```

[It helps when you know that `\[` is a *command*.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9581117/78845) See [Why should be there a space after '[' and before ']' in the Bash Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9581064/78845) for an explanation.