# What is wrong with these formats for Unix Shell Scripting Comparing Strings

Tags: bash, unix

I've been reading through StackExchange posts on scripting and none of the things that I have tried are working as I would expect.

Also this is my 1st shell script.

```
# Script File Begin
echo "Enter yes | no"
read uInput

if ["$uInput" != "n"]; then
  echo "Yes"
fi
```

The issue is when I run this no matter how I try the `if` condition I keep getting `line 5: n: command not found`

I have tried different iterations such as

```
[["$uInput" != "n*"]]
[["$uInput" != n*]]
[[$uInput != n*]]
["$uInput" != "n*"]
["$uInput" != n*]
[$uInput != "n*"]
[$uInput != n*]
```

But they all tell me the same thing line 5: n: command not found.

What am I missing?

Comment: You need space inbetween brackets and text `[ "$uInput" != "n" ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spaces in Bash are crucial not optional. Change the if statement to:

```
if [ "$uInput" != "n" ]; then
```

---

If you are wondering why? see this:

[Why should be there a space after '[' and before ']' in the Bash Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581064/why-should-be-there-a-space-after-and-before-in-the-bash-script/30916636#30916636)

Comment: If you are posting this as answer at least explain why spaces are required.

Comment: Thank you both. I'm big on always taking out white-spaces. Guess I'll have to stop doing that.

Comment: Also for additional information [[ $uInput != n* ]] will check for pattern matching anything with n in the front (n, no, nope, none, nada etc.)