# I thought brackets in BASH were for boolean tests

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I try to run this BASH script, and it says on line 4 that it is missing a bracket.

```
#!/bin/bash

#Given an integer value, write a script to check to see if it is between     10 and 20(inclusive)
if [$value -le 20] && [$value -ge 10]; then
        echo "$value in in range"
else
        echo " $value is out of range"
fi
```

I'm doing this via SSH on a Linux server.

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

You need to put spaces  before and after brackets.

```
#!/bin/bash

#Given an integer value, write a script to check to see if it is between     10 and 20(inclusive)
if [ $value -le 20 ] && [ $value -ge 10 ]; then
        echo "$value in in range"
else
        echo " $value is out of range"
fi
```

Here is the explanation why we need to do that
[Why should there be a space after '[' and before ']' in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581064/why-should-be-there-a-space-after-and-before-in-the-bash-script)