# ./MakeOVPN.sh: line 12: [!-fDanielIphone.crt]: command not found

Tags: linux, bash, raspberry-pi2

I am trying to make a *VPN* using open vpn on my raspberry pi, and I am currently typing a file using the terminal to create a profile script for the devices I want to connect. Using the step by step guide by *BBC*. I have been trying to fix this problem for about an hour now and I keep getting the same error please help.

```
#!/bin/bash
DEFAULT="Default.txt"
FILEEXT=".ovpn"
CRT=".crt"
KEY=".3des.key"
CA="ca.crt"
TA="ta.key"

echo "Please enter an existing Client Name:"
read NAME

if [!-f$NAME$CRT]; then
echo "[ERROR]: Client Public Key Certificate not found: $NAME$CRT"
exit
fi
echo "Client's cert found:$NAME$CR"
if [!-f$NAME$KEY]; then
echo "[ERROR]: Client 3des Private Key not found:$NAME$KEY"
exit
fi
echo "Client's Private Key found:$NAME$KEY"
```

[Error From Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvfnK.jpg)

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate (not marking it as one), but relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581064/why-should-be-there-a-space-after-and-before-in-the-bash-script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add additional spaces inside your if statement:

```
if [ ! -f $NAME$CRT ]; then
```

The complete script is now:

```
#!/bin/bash
DEFAULT="Default.txt"
FILEEXT=".ovpn"
CRT=".crt"
KEY=".3des.key"
CA="ca.crt"
TA="ta.key"

echo "Please enter an existing Client Name:"
read NAME

if [ ! -f $NAME$CRT ]; then
echo "[ERROR]: Client Public Key Certificate not found: $NAME$CRT"
exit
fi
echo "Client's cert found:$NAME$CR"
```

Here's a demonstration showing that it works:

```
$ chmod +x ./myscript 

$ touch foo.crt

$ ./myscript 
Please enter an existing Client Name:
foo
Client's cert found:foo

$ ./myscript
Please enter an existing Client Name:
bar
[ERROR]: Client Public Key Certificate not found: bar.crt
```

Comment: `test` syntax is just plain weird, and `bash` follows it pretty closely, though there are some extensions.  If the pi doesn't have help installed, this link might help: http://www.computerhope.com/unix/test.htm  To make life fun, under `sh`, `[` is just a link to `test`  While this command is built into `bash`, it keeps the same syntax.

Comment: I seemed to get the same error :/                                                                        
./MakeOVPN.sh: line 12: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
./MakeOVPN.sh: line 12: `if[ ! -f $NAME$CRT ]; then'

Comment: @EdgarRokyan once i have done that i get command not found error on all the my if statements ...?

Comment: @DanTheGamer Can you update your question after following this advice, and include the new errors? Also,  [ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) is helpful for these things.

Comment: @thatotherguy Thanks for your great edit! Now the answer looks much more clear!

Comment: @DanTheGamer do you really see no difference between your code and code from my answer? Edit your *if* statements properly as it's mentioned in the answer.

Comment: @EdgarRokyan Sorry i didn't much notice in the reedit of the answer and allowed me to fix the problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score -2):

```
Try this 

#!/bin/bash
`DEFAULT="Default.txt"
FILEEXT=".ovpn"
CRT=".crt"
KEY=".3des.key"
CA="ca.crt"
TA="ta.key"

echo "Please enter an existing Client Name:"
read NAME

if[ !-f $NAME$CRT ]; then
echo "[ERROR]: Client Public Key Certificate not found: $NAME$CRT"
exit
fi
echo "Client's cert found:$NAME$CR"
```

Comment: ./MakeOVPN.sh: line 12: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
./MakeOVPN.sh: line 12: `if[ ! -f $NAME$CRT ]; then'

Comment: This is pretty close, but it's missing vital spaces after `if` and after the `!`. Without this, it's not valid syntax.

Comment: See [Edgar's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35512947/1899640) for a working script, including how to test that it works. Your script (ignoring the leading backtick) gives ``./myscript: line 12: syntax error near unexpected token `then'  ./myscript: line 12: `if[ !-f $NAME$CRT ]; then`` because of the missing spaces.

Answer (score -2):

All I did was add a space after the `if` and it got past your error.

```
#!/bin/bash
DEFAULT="Default.txt"
FILEEXT=".ovpn"
CRT=".crt"
KEY=".3des.key"
CA="ca.crt"
TA="ta.key"

echo "Please enter an existing Client Name:"
read NAME

if [ ! -f $NAME$CRT ]; then
echo "[ERROR]: Client Public Key Certificate not found: $NAME$CRT"
exit
fi
echo "Client's cert found:$NAME$CR"
```

Comment: This gets me to the next bit but i also get an error about the command not found and the statement isnt run console below

Comment: pi@raspberrypi:/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys $ ./MakeOVPN.sh
Please enter an existing Client Name:
DanielIphone
./MakeOVPN.sh: line 12: [!-fDanielIphone.crt]: command not found
Client's cert found:DanielIphone
./MakeOVPN.sh: line 18: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
./MakeOVPN.sh: line 18: `if[!-f$NAME$KEY]; then'
pi@raspberrypi:/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys $

Comment: This does not check whether the file exists. It instead tries to execute a command named by a glob, which is certainly not the intention.

Comment: I wasn't attempting to fix your entire script, I was just attempting to get past your initial error.  I have updated the code to check for file exists, which what I believe you are asking for now.

Comment: This still does not work: there is a missing space before the final `]`. Please see [Edgar's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35512947/1899640) for how to correctly check that the file doesn't exist, including how to test the script to verify that it works.

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect the changes you mentioned and to follow Edgar's answer.  Thank you.