# Compare result of command with string in bash

Tags: string, bash, variables, if-statement

I have a string and a command result so I want to compare them:

```
A="Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination"

B=$(iptables -L)

if [ "$A" == "$B"]; then
    echo "True"
else
    echo "False"
fi
```

But it returns `False`.

Comment: No.. This is not working really..

Comment: You need a space before the closing bracket like this:`if [ "$A" == "$B" ]; then`. Also it is better to use single equal for compatibility reasons. like `if [ "$A" = "$B" ]; then`.

Comment: Does anyone know of a good canonical duplicate for this?  It is a quite common problem.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler We have tried to compile a list of common Bash questions in the [`bash` tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info).  It still needs improvement but the canonical dupe I think you are looking for is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581064/why-should-be-there-a-space-after-and-before-in-the-bash-script

Comment: @tripleee:  It seems the syntax error was only part of the trouble so I won't be closing his as a dupe.  But thanks for the info about the list of common Bash questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's due to the different amount of whitespace used. You can find that out using the following command:

```
diff -u <(iptables -L) - <<EOF | cat -A
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
EOF
```

Output:

```
--- /dev/fd/63^I2016-04-11 08:59:52.663962140 +0200$
+++ -^I2016-04-11 08:59:52.666667769 +0200$
@@ -1,8 +1,8 @@$
 Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)$
-target     prot opt source               destination         $
+target     prot opt source               destination$
 $
 Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)$
-target     prot opt source               destination         $
+target     prot opt source               destination$
 $
 Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)$
-target     prot opt source               destination         $
+target     prot opt source               destination$
```

You see, the `iptables -L` command appends whitespace after `destination`.

To remove that whitespace, you can use sed:

```
iptables -L | sed 's/[[:space:]]*$//'
```

If you also fix the [syntax error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36541774/171318) discovered by Jonathan Leffler, your code should work.

Let me add, that the way you are checking if *"the firewall is not active"* might be to weak. (a) you see, the `iptables -L` command is not really meant to be used for text processing. (b) somebody might have added a custom chain but no rules in it. This would let your check fail.

I don't have really an idea how to do it better. Probably changing firewall rules is meant to be a task executed by the administrator himself rather than by programs. :)

Answer (score 2):

Spacing!

Wrong:

```
if [ "$A" == "$B"]; then
```

Right:

```
if [ "$A" == "$B" ]; then
```

`[` is a command; it requires spaces around its separate arguments (and around its name, `[`), and its last argument must be `]`.  There are grounds to argue that `=` rather than `==` is more portable (but `==` works OK in Bash).

Comment: This is wrong.. because in all states it returns false

Comment: The syntax error is correctly identified and fixed.  If you also have problems with the spacing in your string, that is a separate bag'o'worms which is hard for anyone not on your machine to resolve.  So, you would get a syntax error from the `test` (aka `[`) command when you ran what you showed.  The test might also fail after the syntax is fixed because of spacing problems.

Answer (score 1):

It doesnt match because of whitespaces at end in `iptables -L`

```
A=$(cat <<EOF
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
EOF
)
B="$(iptables -L)"

diff -Z <(echo "$A") <(iptables -L) && echo "True" || echo "False"
```

check this:

[image: meld differences]

btw invoked the `meld` command like this:  `meld <(echo "$A") <(iptables -L)` (meld is a visual diff tool)

Comment: When It returns `false` it shows some junc data related to diff command. how can I discard them and just print `false`?

Comment: @MLSC use this: `diff -q -Z <(echo "$A") <(iptables -L) && echo "True" || echo "False"`, here the `-q` option mean s `quiet` i.e  `-q, --brief
              report only when files differ
`