# korn shell error [: missing `]'

Tags: shell, sh, ksh

I am learning Korn shell which is based on Bourne shell. Below is my really simple code.

```
read ab
if [ $ab = "a" || $ab = "A" ] ; then
    echo hi
fi
```

For some reason `||` operator is giving me the error:

```
[: missing `]'
a: command not found
```

Comment: The `||` is interpreted by the shell, not by the `[` command (yes, `[` is a command). So `[` is invoked with arguments `$ab = "a"`, and it complains about the missing `]`. You could use `-o`, which is the "or" command for `[`, but the method in @codeforester is probably a better way to do it.

Comment: @KeithThompson - I have come to understand that `-o` has been deprecated in more recent version of Bash.  Not sure about ksh though.

Comment: @codeforester, it's actually the POSIX spec that marked it obsolescent, not any particular shell.

Comment: These problems really do become less common if you use `test`: `if test "$ab" = a || test "$ab" = A; then ...` is less error prone.

Comment: Your use of quotes is exactly backwards.  There is no need to quote the string `a`, but there is good reason to quote `"$ab"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to write your `if` condition is:

```
read ab
if [ "$ab" = "a" ] || [ "$ab" = "A" ]; then
  echo hi
fi
```

With `[ ... ]`, it is essential to put the variables in double quotes.  Otherwise, shell will fail with a syntax error if the variables expand to nothing or if their expansion contains spaces.

---

See also:

- [Why should there be a space after '[' and before ']' in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581064/why-should-there-be-a-space-after-and-before-in-bash)
- [How to use double or single brackets, parentheses, curly braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188199/how-to-use-double-or-single-brackets-parentheses-curly-braces)
- [BashFAQ - What is the difference between test, single, and double brackets?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031)

Comment: I am using ${ab}, do you still recommend using double quotes?

Comment: @Mint.K: Yes. `${ab}` will still expand to two or more words if it contains white space.

Comment: @Mint.K, `${ab}` is no different at all from `$ab` unless you're performing a concatenation operation with a string that starts with a character that's legal as part of a shell variable name (ie. `${ab}_foo`).

Answer (score 1):

If you use ksh or a modern bash you can use the non-standard `[[` ... `]]` instead of `[` ... `]`.

This has two benefits:

1. You can use `||` inside `[[` ... `]]`
2. Variable expansions do not need quotes.

This makes it safe and shorter to write

```
[[ $ab = a || $ab = A ]]
```