# How To Compare Number Of Lines In 2 Files Using IF/Then Bash Command

Tags: linux, bash, unix, if-statement, wc

I would like to compare the line counts of two separate files. While I have tried using `wc -l` in the comparison, I'm struggling to get it working properly.

I have:

```
if [ "$(wc -l file1.txt)" == "$(wc -l file2.txt)" ]; then echo "Warning: No Match!"; fi
```

However, the if/then statement does not return the correct output.

If file 1 and 2 have the same number of lines, what is the proper way of writing this code?

File1.txt:

```
example1
example2
example3
```

File2.txt:

```
example4
example5
example6
```

Update: We found that the `wc -l` command must return a digit only for the comparison. Unlike the question [Why should there be a space after '[' and before ']' in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581064/why-should-there-be-a-space-after-and-before-in-bash), this question requires using `wc -l` to get an integer that can be compared the number of lines in separate files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
if [ "$(wc -l < file1.txt)" -eq "$(wc -l < file2.txt)" ]; then echo 'Match!'; else echo 'Warning: No Match!'; fi
```

Examples for above code:
Let's say we have following Input_files:

```
cat file1.txt
I
am
Cookie

cat file2.txt

I
am
Cookie
```

Now since we could see number of lines are not equal in both the files so following result will come.

```
if [ "$(wc -l < file1.txt)" -eq "$(wc -l < file2.txt)" ]; then echo 'Match!'; else echo 'Warning: No Match!'; fi
Warning: No Match!
```

Now if we make both the file's lines equal now as follows.

```
cat file1.txt
I
am
Cookie
cat file2.txt
I
am
Cookie
```

Now when we run same code it will give as follows.

```
if [ "$(wc -l < file1.txt)" -eq "$(wc -l < file2.txt)" ]; then echo 'Match!'; else echo 'Warning: No Match!'; fi
Match!
```

Comment: This works for me Ravinder. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but running two command substitutions and comparing their output is a code smell. I would try to refactor it to a more idiomatic flow, perhaps with a single `wc` or an Awk script.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a space in between your brackets and your comparison expression:

```
if [ <expression> ]; then echo "Then Do Something"; fi
```

So in your case it would be:

```
if [ "$(wc -l file1.txt)" -eq "$(wc -l file2.txt)" ]; then echo "Warning: No Match!"; fi
```

Comment: This will give error since `!` is present in echo with " and it has a special meaning, when you change `"` to `'` then it should be good.

Comment: This answer actually doesn't work because `wc -l file1.txt` does not return an integer.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the double `=` is also wrong, though Bash allows it.

Comment: updated to use `-eq`