# Bash: Check whether a file has a timestamp in the middle of the filename

Tags: bash

I've been trying to check and move a file based on whether the file has a timestamp at the end or not. Here's what I have tried. What am I doing wrong?

```
while read product; do
        if [ -f ${PRODUCT_HOME}/file.*.zip]; then
                echo "Has timestamp."
                mv ${PRODUCT_HOME}/file.*.zip /home/has_time_stamp/file.zip
        else
                echo "No timestamp"
                mv ${PRODUCT_HOME}/file.zip /home/no_time_stamp/file.zip
        fi
done <product_details.txt
```

Error:

> test.sh: 56: [: missing ]

Comment: `[ -f ${PRODUCT_HOME}/file.*.zip];` should be `[ -f ${PRODUCT_HOME}/file.*.zip ];`, note the extra space. EDIT: but that doesn't seem right either, what if it matches more than one files?

Comment: Canonical question: [Why should there be a space after '\[' and before '\]' in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581064/why-should-there-be-a-space-after-and-before-in-bash) - Also, https://www.shellcheck.net tells you about problems like this one.

Comment: It worked. Thanks.