# [: -ne: unary operator expected

Tags: shell, while-loop

I'm trying to work on a script that will search for a certain variable in an array.   Unfortunately the system I'm running changes the order of the array based on other variables at the time.  I know the first seven characters of what I'm looking for will be RPT_NUM so I tried the following while loop, but I keep getting the error  [: -ne: unary operator expected

```
START=5
MYVAR=( $(/usr/sbin/asterisk -rx "rpt showvars 47168"))

#VAR=${MYVAR[3]}

VAR="${MYVAR[START]}"

CURVAR= echo "${VAR:0:7}"
echo $VAR

while ["$CURVAR" -ne "RPT_NUM" ]
do

        let START+=1
        CURVAR= echo "${VAR:0:7}"
        echo "End loop"
done
STATUS=echo "${VAR: -1}"

echo $STATUS
```

I'm fairly new and still learning so any help would be great.

Comment: You need a space after the `[`.

Comment: Also, `CURVAR= echo "${VAR:0:7}"` et al. don’t do what I think you think they do. May I recommend https://www.shellcheck.net/?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why should there be a space after '\[' and before '\]' in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581064/why-should-there-be-a-space-after-and-before-in-bash)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I"ll check out shellcheck.net.  Also, with adding the space I now get:  [: : integer expression expected

Comment: @KB3BYJ `-ne` is for numeric comparison. Run `man [` to work the rest out for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your code to the following one:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

START=5
MYVAR=( $(/usr/sbin/asterisk -rx "rpt showvars 47168"))

#VAR=${MYVAR[3]}

VAR="${MYVAR[START]}"

CURVAR="${VAR:0:7}"
echo $VAR

while [ "$CURVAR" == "RPT_NUM" ]
do

  let START+=1
  CURVAR="${VAR:0:7}"
  echo "End loop"
done
STATUS="${VAR:-1}"

echo $STATUS
```

1. Change the condition expression in the while loop to this:

```sh
while [ "$CURVAR" == "RPT_NUM" ]
```

2. Change the subshell expression to this:

```sh
CURVAR="${VAR:0:7}"   
...    
STATUS="${VAR:-1}"
```

Comment: `CURVAR= echo "${VAR:0:7}"` is still nonsense.