# cURL: how can I return 0 if status is 200?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, curl

How can I return 0 when the response status is 200?

Right now I'm able to get the status, e.g., 200 with the following command:

```
curl -LI http://google.com -o /dev/null -w '%{http_code}\n' -s
```

But I need to turn this 200 in a return of 0.

How can I achieve this?

I tried the following command, but it doesn't return:

```
if [$(curl -LI http://google.com -o /dev/null -w '%{http_code}\n' -s) == "200"]; then echo 0
```

Comment: Isn't the return code 0 if the command is successfult? Why not just use `$?`

Comment: The code you showed should not run due to syntax errors. Also see [How to use Shellcheck](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](https://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Comment: cross-posted: https://superuser.com/q/1358026/4714

Comment: If this weren't already closed, I would be closing it as a duplicate of [Why should there be spaces around `[` and `]` in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581064/why-should-there-be-spaces-around-and-in-bash)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks like you need some spaces and a `fi`. This works for me:

```
if [ $(curl -LI http://google.com -o /dev/null -w '%{http_code}\n' -s) == "200" ]; then echo 0; fi
```

Answer (score 22):

You can also use the `-f` [parameter](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html):

> (HTTP) Fail silently (no output at all) on server errors. This is mostly done to better enable scripts etc to better deal with failed attempts.

So:

```
curl -f -LI http://google.com
```

Will return status 0 if the call was sucessful.

Answer (score 3):

The most simple way is to check for curl's exit code.

```
curl --fail -LI http://google.com -o /dev/null -w '%{http_code}\n' -s > /dev/null
echo $?
```

Output:

```
0
```

And

```
curl --fail -LI http://g234234oogle.com -o /dev/null -w '%{http_code}\n' -s > /dev/null
echo $?
```

Output:

```
6
```

Please note that `--fail` is necessary here ([details in this answer](https://superuser.com/a/657174/926024)). Also note, as pointed out by [Bob](https://superuser.com/users/117590/bob) in the comments <sup>(see footnote)</sup>, that in case of a non-`200` **success** code, this will still return `0`.

If you don't want to use that for whatever reason, here's the other approach:

```
http_code=$(curl -LI http://google.com -o /dev/null -w '%{http_code}\n' -s)
if [ ${http_code} -eq 200 ]; then
    echo 0
fi
```

The reason your code isn't working is because you **have** to add spaces within the brackets.

<sub>(Copied from my answer on Super User (Stack Exchange site) where the OP crossposted the [by now deleted](https://superuser.com/questions/1358026/how-can-i-use-curl-to-return-0-when-the-response-status-is-200-in-a-bash-script) question)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use the Boolean operator `&&`:

```
[ $(curl -LI http://google.com -o /dev/null -w '%{http_code}\n' -s) == "200" ] && echo 0
```

The second command will be executed only if the first part is True.