# Unable to execute the If condition in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, shellexecute

I need to check if container is already present with specific name. 
Using if statement for same, however container is present with same name but i am not sure why if statement is not running successfully.

```
if [`echo password | sudo -S docker ps -all|grep test|cut -d' ' -f1`]
then
statements
else
statements
```

container with test name is present but its always going inside the else statement. Could you help me on this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why should there be a space after '\[' and before '\]' in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9581064/608639)

Comment: Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in addition to @ÔHARA Kazutaka information.

`-all` does not exists, try `--all` instead.

The `--quiet --filter name=test` options are going to make `docker` filters output using the container's name, and make it prints to the standard output the `CONTAINER ID` if a container exists.

Give a try to this:

```
container_name=test

container_id=$(echo password | sudo -S docker ps --all --quiet --filter name="${container_name}")

if [ ! -z "${container_id}" ] ; then
  printf "%s is the id of the container with name '%s'\n" "${container_id}" "${container_name}"
else
  printf "no docker container with name '%s' has been found.\n" "${container_name}"
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

You need blanks between `[`, `]` and `` ` ``, i.e. :

```
if [ `echo password | sudo -S docker ps -all|grep test|cut -d' ' -f1` ]
```

Also, you need `fi` after the last line.