# I am trying to store the outputs of ls in an array

Tags: arrays, bash

When using the Linux command "ls", I list all of the files in a directory. I am trying to store the results of the command ls in an array in bash, and then I want to be able to print each element of the array out.

This is what I've tried.

```
> file_array=( $<ls>) )
```

and

```
> file_array= 'ls'
```

I get an error with the first one, and my array with just print out "ls" with the second one.

Answer (score 3):

It's [not a good idea](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) to parse the output of `ls`.  If you must do that, the right syntax would be:

```
files=($(ls))
```

You can use a glob instead:

```
files=(*)          # store file names in an array
declare -p files   # show the contents of array

for file in "${files[@]}"; do
  # do something with file
done
```

In your second statement, you have a space after `=` which is [not the right syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9581064/6862601) for assignments.