# How to write if-else in shell and echo the ouput to a variable

Tags: linux, shell, if-statement, unix

Checking whether the reddis is working using this command

`redis-cli ping` if output is PONG redis is working.

How to re-write this in shell script like this

```
#!/bin/bash
redis_metrics=$(redis-cli ping)

if [$redis_metrics == PONG]
then
        echo "100"
else
        echo "0"
fi
```

Need to assign the echo output value to a variable - redis_status

Comment: `if [...]; then redis_status=100; echo "100"; else redis_status=0; echo "0"; fi`??

Comment: See also [Why should there be a space after '\[' and before '\]' in Bash?](/questions/9581064/why-should-there-be-a-space-after-and-before-in-bash)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why should there be a space after '\[' and before '\]' in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581064/why-should-there-be-a-space-after-and-before-in-bash) Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this one :

```
#!/bin/bash
redis_metrics=$(redis-cli ping)

if [ $redis_metrics == PONG ]
then
        redis_status=100
        echo "100"
else
        redis_status=0
        echo "0"
fi
```

Comment: Storing the intermediate result in a variable you never use again is useless, though. Simply `if [ "$(redis-cli ping)" = "PONG" ]; then` (notice also the required spaces inside the `[ ... ]`!)... though if `redis-cli` is at all competently written, it will reflect the result in its status code also; so you can simply say `if redis-cli ping; then`

Comment: have an issue if i run it cron it is not working. any inputs. the same if i run in terminal it is working