# do-while loop using user input in shell scritping

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I am a beginner in bash scripting. and i look for similar questions but none gave me the results am looking for.

I want to create a shell that keep giving the user some options to choose from while the choice is not exit

Here is my code

```
choice=0

while [$choice!=4]
do
    echo "please choose the operation you want!"
    echo "1) Delete Data"
    echo "2) Insert Data"
    echo "3) Get Number of customers"
    echo "4) Exit"
    choice=$1
    if [$choice=1]; then
       echo "you have chosen to Delete Data"
    elif [$choice=2]; then
       echo "you have chosen to Insert Data"
    elif [$choice=3]; then
       echo "you have chosen to Get number of customers"
    fi  # EOF if
done
```

As you can see that i want my code to keep asking for the user options until the answer is not exit.
My Question is this code gives me an infinite loop.

Comment: Read up on `select`, and on proper syntax for using `[`.

Comment: Put a shebang on your script and paste it at https://shellcheck.net  should get you  started.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581064/why-should-there-be-spaces-around-and-in-bash

Answer (score 2):

Bash, ksh or zsh provides you with the `select` command that is exactly designed to present numbered options menu:

To get the usage of the `select` command, type `help select` in your bash terminal.

> **`select`**: `select NAME` [`in WORDS` … `;`] `do COMMANDS; done`
>
> Select words from a list and execute commands.
>
> The `WORDS` are expanded, generating a list of words. The set of expanded words is printed on the standard error, each preceded by a number. If `in WORDS` is not present, `in "$@"` is assumed.  The `PS3` prompt is then displayed and a line read from the standard input.  If the line consists of the number corresponding to one of the displayed words, then `NAME` is set to that word.  If the line is empty,  `WORDS` and the prompt are redisplayed. If `EOF` is read, the command completes.  Any other value read causes `NAME` to be set to `null`.  The line read is saved in the variable `REPLY`.  `COMMANDS` are executed after each selection until a break command is executed.
>
> Exit Status:
>
> Returns the status of the last command executed.

Here is an implementation of it with your selection menu:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

choices=('Delete Data' 'Insert Data' 'Get Number of customers' 'Exit')

PS3='Please choose the operation you want: '

select answer in "${choices[@]}"; do
  case "$answer" in
    "${choices[0]}")
      echo 'You have chosen to Delete Data.'
      ;;

    "${choices[1]}")
      echo 'You have chosen to Insert Data.'
      ;;

    "${choices[2]}")
      echo 'You have chosen to Get number of customers.'
      ;;

    "${choices[3]}")
      echo 'You have chosen to Exit.'
      break
      ;;

    *)
      printf 'Your answer %q is not a valid option!\n' "$REPLY"
      ;;
  esac
done
unset PS3
```

Another implementation of the `select` command, using arguments rather than an array of choices:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env ksh

PS3='Please choose the operation you want: '

set -- 'Delete Data' 'Insert Data' 'Get Number of customers' 'Exit'

select answer; do
  case "$answer" in
    "$1")
      echo 'You have chosen to Delete Data.'
      ;;

    "$2")
      echo 'You have chosen to Insert Data.'
      ;;

    "$3")
      echo 'You have chosen to Get number of customers.'
      ;;

    "$4")
      echo 'You have chosen to Exit.'
      break
      ;;

    *)
      printf 'Your answer %q is not a valid option!\n' "$REPLY"
      ;;
  esac
done
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use while loop with conditional 'case' syntax, try this:

```
while true
do
    echo "1) Delete Data"
    echo "2) Insert Data"
    echo "3) Get Number of customers"
    echo "4) Exit"
    
    echo -ne "Enter your choice [0-4] > \c"
    read choice

    case "$choice" in
        1) echo "you have chosen to Delete Data" ; break
           ;;

        2) echo "you have chosen to Insert Data"; break
           ;;

        3) echo "you have chosen to Get number of customers"; break
           ;;

        4) exit
           ;;
           
        *) clear
           ;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: thanks for helping but this code gave me an infinite loop and this error: xxxxxxx.ksh[18]: read: no query process

Comment: The read -p syntaxe works only with bash shell.

Comment: for `ksh` replace `read -p` with `read var?"Msg w spaces"` , Good luck to all.

Answer (score -1):

i found the error. it was statement typing issue not in the algorithm
my new code is

```
    while [ "$(read choice)"!="4" ]
    do
    if [ "$choice"="1" ]; then
       echo "you have chosen to Delete Data"
    elif [ "$choice"="2" ]; then
       echo "you have chosen to Insert Data"
    elif [ "$choice"="3" ]; then
       echo "you have chosen to Get number of customers"
    fi  # EOF if

    echo "please choose the operation you want!"
    echo "1) Delete Data"
    echo "2) Insert Data"
    echo "3) Get Number of customers"
    echo "4) Exit"
done
```

Comment: This will not work right, since `$(read choice)` reads into the `choice` variable in a subshell, and variable assignments that happen in a subshell don't affect the main shell. Also, `read choice` doesn't *print* anything (it just sets a variable), `$(read choice)` will give the empty string rather than the read value, so the comparison to "4" won't work. And there's another reason it won't work: you need spaces around the operator in a comparison (that is, `[ "a" != "b" ]` rather than `[ "a"!="b" ]`). [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) will spot many of these common mistakes.