# Can I use functions as tests in a Bash case statement?

Tags: bash, case

can I use a function instead of regular patterns, strings etc. in a bash `case` statement like this?

```
#!/bin/bash

var="1"

is_one () {
[$var -eq 1]
}

case $var in

    is_one) 
    "var is one"
    ;;
    
    *) 
    "var is not one"
    break
    ;;
    
esac
```

Comment: Btw: You don't need `break` inside bash's `case` statement. Bash uses `;;` instead. Also, you need spaces around `[` and `]`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use functions in statements where could also use programs like `test`/`[`, that is `while`, `until`, and `if`. The `case` statement however allows only patterns, no programs/functions.

Either use

```
if is_one; then
  echo "var is one"
else
  echo "var is not one"
done
```

or

```
case $var in
  1) echo "var is one" ;;
  *) echo "var is not one" ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 4):

Of course you can use a function, but the function should *print* the *pattern* you want to match as a glob.  That's what `case` operates on.

```sh
is_one () {
    echo 1
}

case $var in
   "$(is_one)") echo 'It matched!';;
   *) echo ':-(';;
esac
```

Perhaps a better design if you really want to use a function is to write a one which (doesn't contain syntax errors and) returns a non-zero exit code on failure.  In this particular case, encapsulating it in a function doesn't really make much sense, but of course you can:

```sh
is_one () {
    [ "$1" -eq 1 ]
}
if is_one "$var"; then
    echo 'It matched!"
else
    echo ':-('
fi
```

Notice the [non-optional spaces inside `[...]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581064/why-should-be-there-a-space-after-and-before-in-the-bash-script) and also the [quoting,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable) and the use of a parameter instead of hard-coding a global variable.

Furthermore, note that `-eq` performs numeric comparisons, and will print an unnerving error message if `$var` is not numeric.  Perhaps you would prefer to use `[ "$1" = "1" ]` which performs a simple string comparison.  This is also somewhat closer in semantics to what `case` does.

Comment: So it doesn't work to evaluate whether the method "matches", e.g. is true or falsey? In the end, for truth-tests I need a dangling `if-else statement` ?

Comment: You can of course write a function which returns true or false, but `case` works exclusively on patterns, so then you'd have to use a different flow control statement, yes. I don't see how you would need specifically a "dangling `if-else` statement" if I understand correctly what you mean by that. With the definition in your question (except of course with the syntax errors fixed, as pointed out elsewhere) you could do `if ! is_one; then echo "is not"; fi` if you only want to cover the failure.

Comment: @vonspotz : For _trueish_  and _falsey_, you need `if`, `until` or `while`. The reason is that they _run a command_ and react on its exit code, while `case` does not run a command.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is that `if`... `elif`... distinguishes its alternatives based on the **exit** codes of the commands being executed, while `case`.... bases it on **string** values. Your function, when invoked, exhibits its result only via its exit code.

If you want to use your function with a `case`, you need to turn this exit code into a string, for instance like this:

```
is_one
var=$? # Store exit code as a string into var
case $var in
1) echo "exit code is one" ;;
101) echo "exit code is onehundredandone" ;;
*) echo "I do not care what the exit code is" ;;
esac
```

Comment: What's with `echo "true"` or `echo "false"` ? Wouldn't that also be possible without quotes?

Comment: Quoting is optional here, but good practice especially for beginners. In short, quote everything until you find a situation where quoting actually breaks something.  For detailed advice, see [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Comment: But see also [Why is testing “$?” to see if a command succeeded or not, an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313216/why-is-testing-to-see-if-a-command-succeeded-or-not-an-anti-pattern)

Comment: @triplee: It often is, but not always. Imagine the case that you run some functions, need to collect their exit codes and later on make a decision. There is no alternative to storing `$?` somewhere. Of course in this concrete toy example, nobody would really want to use `case`, and with using `if`, we avoid the problem alltogether. But the OP wants (perhaps as a programming exercise) see whether `case` could be used here too, and then we need `$?`. Actually, the reason why I assigned it to `var` instead of using it directly inside `case` statement, is to avoid the common pitfalls with `$?`.

Comment: @vonspotz: You have to be careful for instance when the string contains several spaces in a row. For instance, `echo "I am        hungry"` and `echo I am        hungry` produce different output.