# Simple bash script output

Tags: bash, syntax

I try to write simple script to read temperature:

```
cpu=$(cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/temp)
if [$cpu -ge 50000]; then
echo "OK"
else
echo "Not OK"
fi
```

echo $cpu is fine: 64000 but script output is:

```
myscript.sh: 2: [64000: not found
Not OK
```

What is wrong with line 2?
Thank You.

Comment: Please add a suitable shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) and then paste your script at http://www.shellcheck.net/ and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: See [Why should there be spaces around `[` and `]` in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9581064/2745495)

Answer (score 0):

You want to make a few changes here:

- Add a space between the `[` and the `$cpu`, and before the `]` ([as per the comments above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72335979/simple-bash-script-output#comment127791384_72335979))
- Place the `$cpu` into double quotes, to avoid unexpected results
- Handle the possibility of maximum values, by picking up the maximum (or minimum, or average).

```
cpu="$(cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/temp | sort -nr | head -1)"
if [ "$cpu" -ge 50000 ] ; then
    echo "OK" 
else
    echo "NOT"
fi
```

If you prefer the space-less expressions, you can use the arithmetic expressions

```
cpu="$(cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/temp | sort -nr | head -1)"
if ((cpu>50000)) ; then
    echo "OK" 
else
    echo "NOT"
fi
```