# Bash script command not found error in while loop

Tags: bash, while-loop, comparison, declare, typeset

I have problem and cant still handle with it. :(
Here is my code

```
declare -i disk_usage_rate=$(df -h /appdata/SCT_CDR | cut -d '%' -f 1 | awk 'NR==2{print $5}')

while ["$disk_usage_rate" -gt 80]
do
...
...
done
```

I get the disk usage rate from df -h command. But in while loop I get the followig error. Btw it is bash script.

> bash: [84: command not found

I tried so many things but I didnt solve yet.

Comment: https://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing space near square brackets used in while loop such as below -

```
declare -i disk_usage_rate=$(df -h /appdata/SCT_CDR | cut -d '%' -f 1 | awk 'NR==2{print $5}')

while [ "$disk_usage_rate" -gt 80 ]
do
...
...
done
```

> A bit of history: this is because '[' was historically not a
>   shell-built-in but a separate executable that received the expresson
>   as arguments and returned a result. If you didn't surround the '['
>   with space, the shell would be searching $PATH for a different
>   filename (and not find it) . – Andrew Medico Jun 24 '09 at 1:13

Ref - [bash shell script syntax error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035396/bash-shell-script-syntax-error)

Comment: thank you very very much i tried to solve it about 1 day. the actually reason should be adhd :( :( thank you a lot. @vivekyad4v

Comment: no problem :) . Just a heads up - If you are satisfied with the answer always upvote it & mark it as correct. This helps us moving :)

Comment: Whether or not `[` is a built-in or external command, it's still a command, not part of the `if` statement or otherwise special syntax.

Answer (score 2):

I see one error : add a space after `'['` and before `']'` on your while line :

```
while [ "$disk_usage_rate" -gt 80 ]
```

Is it better ?

Comment: thank you a lot it was the solve :) :) :)